# How to scale a View without it taking up the space it would have taken if I didn't scale it?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a `View` appear exactly the same as it would normally, except a smaller size. I've tried doing this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getBaseContext());
    final Button b1 = new Button(getBaseContext());
    final Button b2 = new Button(getBaseContext());
    final Button b3 = new Button(getBaseContext());
    b1.setText("button 1");
    b2.setText("button 2");
    b3.setText("button 3");
    b2.setScaleX(0.5f);
    b2.setScaleY(0.5f);
    ll.addView(b1);
    ll.addView(b2);
    ll.addView(b3);
    setContentView(ll);
  }
}
```

It does scale the `View`, but it still takes up the space it would have taken if I didn't scale at all:

[image]

I want to get rid of the invisible space around button 2. The 3 buttons should be compact in the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: you can try overriding `onMeasure` of `Button`. you can do the scaling work if the default implement doesn't handle this.

Answer (score 0):

button2 is measured before it set scale.the width and height of button2 is generated when it called onmeasure before it set scale.so you can't get the right result by doing this.